# PL/SQL procedure with cursors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to check whether any of the column in record set contains data or not.

I have to check 10 columns for the data.  If data is not there it has to exit otherwise continue to the next step.

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statement for each table involved would help us to know what the columns & their data types are.  Version of Oracle would be nice too...

Comment: Please edit your question to give us more details about what you are trying to achieve.  Are you searching for specific values or just that the columns contain *something*, that is, NOT NULL?  Why do you think you need to step through a cursor rather than just selecting a record set using plain SQL?

Answer (score 7):

Try `COALESCE(col_1,col_2,.....) IS NOT NULL`